# How to handle exceptions with stripe

Tags: django, exception, stripe-payments

I am trying to integrate stripe with my django project, so I try to create a `PaymentIntent` and if a network communication with stripe failed I will try to do like this:

```
try:
    intent = stripe.PaymentIntent.create(
        amount=100,
        currency='usd'
    )
    return JsonResponse({
         'clientSecret': intent['client_secret']
    })
except stripe.error.CardError as e:
    pass
except stripe.error.RateLimitError as e:
    pass
except stripe.error.InvalidRequestError as e:
    pass
except stripe.error.AuthenticationError as e:
    pass
except stripe.error.APIConnectionError as e:
    try:
        intent_cancel = stripe.PaymentIntent.cancel(
            intent['id']
        )
    except Exception as e:
        # (If an exception is raised this means that the PaymentIntent was not created, I am right ?)
        # I redirect the user to the payment page and inform him
        # that a network problem has occurred and ask him to repeat his request
        pass
except stripe.error.StripeError as e:
    pass
except Exception as e:
    pass
```

My questions are:

- 1 Is my way of handling the exception right ?
- 2 Can I apply this logic to the other exception ?
- 3 In the documentation they say that we should use an `idempotency_key` to retry the failed requests, how can I implement this ? and what about if I retry the failed request and it fails again, what should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 Stripe API requests in the same `try` block. This means if one succeeds but the other fails due to a connection error you'll treat both as failed. A better flow would be to only have one API operation per try/catch block.

You also have a request to cancel a hardcoded PaymentIntent after your code returns a JSON object. Since the return isn't conditional this is likely dead code.

The cancel logic in the case of a connection error doesn't make sense here. You should only hit this path if the connection failed and the intent wasn't created, so trying to cancel the non-existent PaymentIntent will likely result in yet another error. Instead you should introduce retry logic here. Luckily stripe-python has this built in specifically for network errors: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-python#configuring-automatic-retries

Once all retries have failed, you should probably log that somewhere and inform your user that a problem occurred and that they should try again later.

As for idempotency keys, the Stripe docs have a primer on that here: https://stripe.com/docs/api/idempotent_requests?lang=python

Comment: oops I made an error when creating this post, I have edited my question, thank you for your response !

Comment: how can I know that all retries have failed ? if I add some code in the `stripe.error.APIConnectionError` exception, is this code executed ones all retries failed or it will be executed for each retry ?

Comment: If you set max network retries then that error will only throw once all retries have been exhausted.